# Why didn't \printnoidxglossaries print anything with \cite{} in document?

Tags: bibliographies, glossaries

I have both glossaries and bibliography in my report. I used `\printnoidxglossaries` but it won't show up because of `\cite{}` in my report.. When I removed `\cite{}` then `\printnoidxglossaries` will show up. Why does this happen and do you know how to fix this problem?

Example:

the codes with `\cite{veggie}`:

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage[utf8]
{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]
{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{glossaries}  
\makenoidxglossaries  
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},plural={potatoes},  
 description={starchy tuber}}  
\newglossaryentry{cabbage}{name={cabbage},  
 description={vegetable with thick green or purple leaves}}  
\newglossaryentry{carrot}{name={carrot},  
 description={orange root}}  
\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossaries  
\chapter{Vegetable}
Chop the \gls{cabbage}, \glspl{potato} and \glspl{carrot} \cite{veggie}.  

\begin{thebibliography}{100}

\bibitem{veggie} Vegetable. (2014). \emph{FDA}.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample 1 from above code]
[image: continue]

The code without `\cite{veggie}`, you can see the difference:

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage[utf8]
{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]
{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{glossaries}  
\makenoidxglossaries  
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},plural={potatoes},  
  description={starchy tuber}}  
\newglossaryentry{cabbage}{name={cabbage},  
  description={vegetable with thick green or purple leaves}}  
\newglossaryentry{carrot}{name={carrot},  
  description={orange root}}  
\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossaries  
\chapter{Vegetable}
 Chop the \gls{cabbage}, \glspl{potato} and \glspl{carrot}.  

\begin{thebibliography}{100}

\bibitem{veggie} Vegetable. (2014). \emph{FDA}.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

How to fix this problem?? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I tested your code and both glossary and bibliography is there

Comment: Did you test first code?

Comment: Yes, and then removed `\cite{veggie}` The glossary is printed

Comment: So you tested first code, the glossary did printed? Because it did not printed on mine. But yes, when I removed `\cite{veggie}`, the glossary is printed. I will need `\cite{veggie}` to be in my report as well.

Comment: It's printed in both cases. Do you have a recently modern TeX distribution?

Comment: Interesting. I wondered why did it not printed on my computer.

Comment: ok ah. biblatex is not installed. Let me try to installed them.

Comment: Just to make sure: Sometime you have to run the compiler multiple times to get to the final result...

Comment: Harald - I already run the compiler multiple times but the glossary is not printed yet.

Comment: cfr - can you explain more?

Comment: @Kristin: How could you run the code without having `biblatex` installed?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer, No idea. I think it is old version. I have v2.8 for package `biblatex`.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer, ok `biblatex` is installed (now v2.9) and TeX distribution is recently modern. The result and problem is still same. (Yes I run the compiler multiple times) Any other ideas?

Comment: I just looked at the warnings.. I found this: 

Package glossaries Warning: Empty glossary for \printnoidxglossary[type={main}]
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'veggie' on page 1 undefined on input line 70.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


This warnings were occurred when `\cite{veggie}` is in the code.

Comment: @cfr, thank you for respond. I realized that I don't need 'biblatex' because I don't have a '.bib' file. So I removed it, but there is an addition problem: '\ref' as '?' instead number. If I kept 'biblatex' then it will show the number for '\ref' which is strange.

Comment: do you have any other approach I should try to do?

Comment: Sorry. One more comment... I decided to try to make a new document with only bibliography.

'documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\cite{veggie}
\begin{thebibliography}{100}
\bibitem{veggie} Vegetable. FDA. 1990.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}'

It would gave me few warnings: Citation 'Veggie' on page 1 undefined on input line 54 and there were undefined references... There must be something wrong with '\cite'

Comment: The problem was kinda figure out.. I posted the simpler problem: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211724/cite-is-behaving-oddly-it-will-only-show]. It is believed GUI caused this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because some mess done by the GUI, refer to the linked question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211724/cite-is-behaving-oddly-it-will-only-show] Nothing useful in making them duplicates.